# How does the fetch http parameter increment with the timer setInterval?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I want to do a function with the timer to get the number of pages, whenever the timer runs once, the parameter page by 1
This is my code---

```js
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: '',
      page: 0 ,
    }
  }

  myFunc = () => {
    let myFetchOptions = {
      method: 'GET',
    };

    fetch("http://xxx/Api/screen/screenByAll.ashx?Status=All&ActionNm=8080&page="+this.setState( (page) => page++ )+"&rows=10",myFetchOptions)
    .then( (response) => response.text() )
    .then( (responseText) => {
      const json = JSON.parse(responseText);
      return json;
    } )
    .then(json => this.setState({data: json}) )
    .catch( (error) =>{
      console.error(error);
    } );

  }

  componentWillMount(){
    setInterval(this.myFunc, 3000);
  }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

First of all setState is an asynchronous function and the state of component doesn't get mutated immediately. I guess some recursion can do the job for you. setState has a second parameter which is a callback that is called after the state had muted. You could add a parameted to myFunc(pageNum) and check if its less or equal than the number of page you desire and after the page has beed fetched call the same function myFunc(pageNum + 1).

And if you still need the interval between function call, add myFunc(pageNum + 1) inside a setTimeout like:

```
setTimeout(() => {this.myFunc( pageNum + 1)}, 3000)
```

and call myFunc(0) inside the componentWillMount

Comment: What i want is running all the time, not just running it once, so use setTimeout inappropriate

Comment: Well, then just remove the "if its less or equal than the number of page you desire" part and you should be fine.